Derivative of flow of vector field with respect to the manifold
Let $X$ be a complete vector field on a smooth manifold $M$. Let $\phi^-(-): \mathbb{R} \times M \to M$ denote the flow of $X$. Then for all $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $p_0 \in M$ we know that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\vert_{t=t_0} \left(\phi^t(p_0)\right) =  X(\phi^{t_0}(p_0)),$$
by definition of integral curves and of flow. My question is: what happens if, instead of the "partial" derivative of $\phi$ on $\mathbb{R}$, I take the "partial" derivative on $M$? Is it still the case that
$$ d(\phi^{t_0})(p_0)X(p_0) = X(\phi^{t_0}(p_0)) \ ? $$
I cannot prove this, but it sounds kind of reasonable. I tried to take the "total" derivative of $\phi$ and to see what happens, but I cannot go on from there:
$$ d\phi(t_0,p_0)(1,X(p_0)) = X(\phi^{t_0}(p_0)) + d(\phi^{t_0})(p_0)X(p_0).$$

Yes, it is the case. The equation you want to prove,
$$ d(\phi^{t_0})(p_0)X(p_0) = X(\phi^{t_0}(p_0)), $$
says precisely that the vector field $X$ is $\phi^{t_0}$-related to itself for each $t_0$, or more succinctly, that $X$ is invariant under its own flow. This is a special case of the fact that if two vector fields commute, then each one is invariant under the flow of the other. (In this case, both vector fields are $X$, and $[X,X]=0$.) This is proved in my Introduction to Smooth Manifolds (2nd ed.), Theorem 9.42 and Corollary 9.43.
